# How do I get Windows 8 to measure startup impact?

Tags: windows-8, boot

I did an inplace upgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate to Windows 8 Pro, and am just getting used to Windows 8. Under the Task Manager → Startup tab, I see there's an option showing ["start up impact".](https://superuser.com/questions/495451/what-is-the-startup-impact-column-in-task-manager)

Despite few reboots, the impact is still in "Not measured" state. What should I do to get Windows to measure this report the impact to me?

[image]

Comment: Do you only want it from Windows or any third party tool is welcome?

Comment: @avirk would prefer to do it from within Windows

Comment: Have you tried a few cold starts?

Comment: @Windos I'll admit no, it's been either reboots (in between Windows updates) or wake up from sleep

Comment: I think that will be it. It's the only thing "special" I have done on my PC and the impact is all filled out.

Comment: Strangely enough I did an upgrade too and after a few forced restarts (to fix up symlinks again) I looked into Task Manager the first time and they were all measured.

Comment: Just wild speculation, but maybe this has something to do with SecureBoot? When I upgraded from Win7, I was told that my hardware didn't support SecureBoot, and I see "not measured" as well. Maybe SecureBoot is required to measure startup impact?

Comment: @ekolis interesting speculation, that could be a reason since my hardware doesn't support secure boot. Would still love to know the reason why though

Comment: I had the same problem, but I let it be, and except for a few apps the startup impact is now being measured. So I suggest, you wait a couple more days.

Comment: Just FYI, Start-up impact (which is named "Startup impact" on my installation) works just fine in my VirtualBox installation. So I doubt it requires anything special

Answer (score 1):

This could happen with some of the third party apps where windows is unable to determine the impact.

You can either leave it unrecognized or can try with third party measurement app like Tune Up Utilities.

I suggest you to leave it unrecognized if it doesn't matter a lot to you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the cold boot too but it doesn't measure the impact too. I tried also by disable the program and a proper shutdown and then again enable the program and did a cold boot again but nothing changed. SO there is no way to manually(according to me, if someone has idea he is most welcome) measure the startup impat.

So I recommend to use third party apps like [Soluto](http://www.soluto.com/) which can measure the startup time and also show the solution to make it fast. Or you can use [Argus Boot Accelerator](http://www.speedupboottime.com/en/) for startup items.

Another tool that can measure the startup time is [BootRacer](http://www.greatis.com/bootracer/download.htm), which is free for non-commercial use. The latest version of BootRacer adds support for Windows 8. Now its also available in Windows store.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on several clean loads.

Loaded Intel Rapid Storage Technology driver last.

Don't know all the technicals to it, but it worked for me.